# Why std::cout output overflow?

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve the simple question on *Codeforces* ([round#1 question A](http://codeforces.com/contest/1/problem/A)). For the 16th test case, my code got `-270385980` which should be `27126743055556`, but on my local computer I can get the correct answer. On my computer I compiled it in GCC 4.8, and on *Codeforces*, I used GCC 4.7.

How could it be a negative number? Could anyone give me a hint of what is wrong with my code?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double m, n, a;
    std::cin >> m >> n >> a;
    long long res = static_cast<long>(ceil(m / a)) * static_cast<long>(ceil(n / a));
    std::cout << res;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what input are you providing?

Comment: It's a codeforce thing, I doubt he knows.  But his problem is almost certainly related to integer overflow.

Comment: @user1166140, what's happening is either a `long long` or a `long` on your computer is a 64-bit value, but on the test computer it's a 32-bit value.  Try again, but this time use `int64_t` instead.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - `long long` is required to be at least 64 bits wide.

Comment: @PeteBecker, actually it isn't.  See 4.13.1 of N3337, and also see 4.5.2 and 4.5.3 where they explicitly raise the possibility that a `long long` type could be potentially unable to hold a `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` or enumerable type.

Comment: @PeteBecker, wait, you're an editor on the C++ standard committee?  Ok, I'm willing to be wrong on this one, you probably know better than I do, but please cite where I'm wrong or misreading the standard. :)

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - the minimum sizes of integer types come from C, where they are indirectly specified through `<limits.h>`; `LLONG_MIN` (the smallest value representable in type `long long`) has to be at least -(2^63-1), and `LLONG_MAX` (the largest value representable in type `long long`) has to be at least 2^63-1.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - the reason for all that shifty wording around `char16_t` and `char32_t` is that they are typedefs for `uint_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t`. There is a hypothetical possibility that `int`, `long`, and `long long` could all be 64 bits; in that case, there are values of type `char16_t` and `char32_t` that are too large to represent in a `long long` (i.e., values that are greater than `LLONG_MAX`), so the promotion would go to `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following number : `27126743055556` needs more than 32 bit (length of `long` on a 32bit processor) to be represented, so the `long` is overflowed and you get a negative number.

You should use `long long` in casting.

```
static_cast<long long>(ceil(m / a))
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, it works! So if the multiplier is long type, the result is long type as well, thus on the codeforce website it overflowed (long type on codeforce's machine is probably 32bits?). Even if I use a long long type variable to catch the result, it only got the overflowed result.